# How can the lack of return type polymorphism in untyped languages be alleviated?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism, existential-type

I've been working with Church encoding recently and when I look at a typical type

```haskell
newtype ChurchMaybe a = 
 ChurchMaybe { runChurchMaybe :: forall r . r -> (a -> r) -> r }
```

it looks as if functions with an existential type (`runChurchMaybe`) might behave similarly to functions that are polymorphic in their return type. I haven't fully understood the logic behind existential types though. So I am probably wrong.

Now I've often read that monads are less useful in untyped languages like Javascript, also because of the lack of return type polymorphism. So I wondered if I can ease this shortcoming:

```js
// JS version of Haskell's read

// read :: String -> forall r . (String -> r) -> r
const read = x => cons => cons(x);

// option type

const Some = x => r => f => f(x);
const None =      r => f => r;

console.log(
  read(prompt("any string")) (Array.of) // [a]
);

console.log(
  read(prompt("any string")) (Some) // Some(a)
);

console.log(
  read(prompt("number string")) (x => Number(x)) // Number
);

const append_ = x => y => append => append(x) (y);

const all = x => y => x && y;
const any = x => y => x || y;
const add = x => y => x + y;

const semigroup = append_(true) (false)

semigroup(all); // false
semigroup(any); // true
semigroup(add); // 1
```

Obviously, `read` isn't polymorphic in its return type, because it always  returns a lambda. However, this lambda can serve as a proxy of the actual return value and the context is now able to determine what type this proxy actually produces by passing a suitable constructor.

And while `read` can produce any type, `append_` is limited to types that have a semigroup constraint.

Of course there is now a little noise in the context of such functions, since they return a proxy instead of the actual result.

Is this essentially the mechanism behind the term "return type polymorphism"? This subject seems to be quite complex and so I guess I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this question might be more appropriate in Computer Science or Software Engineering. Though I must also admit that I don't quite understand everything in this question.

Comment: The title of the question might be a little too general, yes. I have difficulties with the terminology. Nevertheless, I think that the question itself is specific enough, with real code sketches.

Comment: @overactor when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Your `read` is just function application with reversed arguments. Likewise `append` for binary functions. They don't provide us anything; you'd be better off just applying functions.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I think that's intentional. Haskell has no universal `read` definition, it inherits the definition of `read` from the `Read a` typeclass which gets provided as an invisible parameter in Haskell as a lookup table. It would make more sense probably if they did `cons.read(x)` instead of `cons(x)`

Comment: @AndrásKovács No offence, but this seems to be rather an argument from authority. In view of your reputation in Haskell your advice is probably right though: "_you'd be better off just applying normal functions_". However, I think `read`/`append_` aren't normal functions, regardless of their argument order. They take their value constructor or type constraint explicitly as an argument. Hence they are more generic than "regular functions".

Comment: Your `ChurchMaybe` type isn't an existential. The constructor doesn't hide any type choices made by its caller. It forces the caller to provide a polymorphic function, which is the opposite of a hidden choice - it's an explicit inability to make a choice.

Comment: @Carl OK, I misunderstood existential types. Thanks for the clarification. I'll look into the subject more closely.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a satisfactory answer to this question. 1, JS is a _totally_ different language to Haskell, so you shouldn't expect a Haskell concept to have an equivalent in JS. (A phrase like "return type polymorphism", which talks about a type, isn't meaningful in an language without types.) 2, as @AndrásKovács points out, your JS `read` doesn't really have any connection to Haskell's `read` - it doesn't parse a value from a string, it's just `flip ($)`. 3, it's unclear what you're asking: the q reads as a collection of loosely related concepts, not a coherent question

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson On your first point, part of the purpose of implementing Haskell-like features in JavaScript is because it gives an opportunity to learn more about type systems by trying to design one. I really like these "implement Haskell in JS" questions because they're more academic than most JS questions.

Comment: @Benjamin 1. I didn't expect that at all. On the contrary, I am excited how many advanced functional concepts I am able to express or at least mimic just with pure, first class functions. 2. When you combine `read` with `prompt` it does parse a value from a `String`. It's all about guidelines or policies in JS. 3. I misunderstood existential types, sorry. I should have omitted them. Otherwise I couldn't see why the question is not coherent. Maybe it is poor in terminology, but not incoherent.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes of course, in an untyped language you can simply ignore types. You can just hack around, make things up as you see fit and produce a code mess. This is sufficient if you don't have the ambition to create something serious. I believe in the opposite. In the absence of a compiler your mind must pitch in. If you see a bunch of Javascript code you need to recognize the underlying types and the morphisms between them. Sure, it is sometimes hard to force yourself to do so. However, I believe you can develop some mastery of types, even as a developer of an untyped language.

Comment: @ftor I apologise. I should have been more aware of my tone. I'd intended my comment to be question-asking advice but I can totally see upon re-reading it now that I just came across as rude. I'm sorry I gave you a bad experience and I hope I haven't put you off continuing to learn this wonderful language. (PS I wasn't ignoring you deliberately, I'm just having a busy week.)

Comment: I'll try to write up a (less rude) answer elaborating on what I meant.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I've been working on a way to adapt Haskell idioms for an untyped environment for months now. To expect others to recognize my intention and every detail is inappropriate. My superficial knowledge of Haskell is also not that useful to express a meaningful question. So, uhm, sorry for the mess.

Comment: @ftor Hope my answer helped. No hard feelings?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Actually, it helped. Everything OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568376/how-can-the-lack-of-return-type-polymorphism-in-untyped-languages-be-alleviated?noredirect=1#comment76144960_44568376) I made an assertion without justifying myself: I said that return type polymorphism isn't a meaningful concept in an untyped language. That was rude of me and I apologise for being so brusque. What I meant was something rather more subtle than what I said, so please allow me to attempt to make amends for my poor communication by explaining in more detail what I was trying to get at. (I hope this answer doesn't come across as condescending; I don't know your base level of knowledge so I'm going to start at the beginning.)

When Haskellers say "return type polymorphism", they're referring to one particular effect of the type class dispatch mechanism. It comes about as the interplay between *dictionary passing* and *bidirectional type inference*. (I'm going to ignore polymorphic `_|_`s like `undefined :: forall a. a` or `let x = x in x :: forall a. a`. They don't really count.)

First, note that type class instances in Haskell are syntactic sugar for explicit dictionary passing. By the time GHC translates your program into its Core intermediate representation, all the type classes are gone. They are replaced with "dictionary" records and passed around as regular explicit arguments; `=>` is represented at runtime as `->`. So code like

```
class Eq a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
instance Eq Bool where
    True == True = True
    False == False = True
    _ == _ = False

headEq :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
headEq _ [] = False
headEq x (y:_) = x == y

main = print $ headEq True [False]
```

is translated into something like

```
-- The class declaration is translated into a regular record type. (D for Dictionary)
data EqD a = EqD { eq :: a -> a -> Bool }
-- The instance is translated into a top-level value of that type
eqDBool :: EqD Bool
eqDBool = EqD { eq = eq }
    where eq True True = True
          eq False False = True
          eq _ _ = False

-- the Eq constraint is translated into a regular dictionary argument
headEq :: EqD a -> a -> [a] -> Bool
headEq _ _ [] = False
headEq eqD x (y:_) = eq eqD x y

-- the elaborator sees you're calling headEq with a ~ Bool and passes in Bool's instance dictionary
main = print $ headEq eqDBool True [False]
```

It works because of *instance coherence*: every constraint has at most one "best" matching `instance` (unless you switch on `IncoherentInstances`, which is usually a bad idea). At the call site of an overloaded function, the elaborator looks at the constraint's type parameter, searches for an instance matching that constraint - either a top-level `instance` or a constraint that's in scope - and passes in the single corresponding dictionary as an argument. (For more on the notion of instance coherence I recommend [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZxTQP1ifo) by Ed Kmett. It's quite advanced - it took me a couple of watches to grasp his point - but it's full of insight.)

Much of the time, as in `headEq`, the constraint's type parameters can be determined by looking only at the types of the overloaded function's arguments, but in the case of polymorphic return values (such as `read :: Read a => String -> a` or `mempty :: Monoid m => m`) the typing information has to come from the call site's context. This works via the usual mechanism of bidirectional type inference: GHC looks at the return value's usages, generates and solves unification constraints to figure out its type, and then uses that type to search for an instance. It makes for a kinda magical developer experience: you write `mempty` and the machine figures out from the context which `mempty` you meant!

(Incidentally, that's why `show . read :: String -> String` is forbidden. `show` and `read` are type class methods, whose concrete implementation isn't known without any clues about the type at which they're being used. The intermediate type in `show . read` - the one you're reading into and then showing from - is ambiguous, so GHC doesn't know how to choose an instance dictionary in order to generate runtime code.)

So "return type polymorphism" is actually a slightly misleading term. It's really a by-word for a particular kind of *type-directed code generation*; its Core representation is just as a regular function whose return type can be determined from the type of its (dictionary) argument. In a language without type classes (or a language without types at all, like JS), you have to simulate type classes with explicit dictionary parameters that are manually passed around by the programmer, as @4Castle has demonstrated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44579662/1523776). You can't do type-directed code generation without types to be directed by!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance back then. Return type polymorphism actually makes no sense in dynamically typed languages. Without a value there is no type to introspect. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to know how to implement functions which need access to the methods of a type class so that they can be polymorphic.

One way to think about type classes is as lookup tables between types and implementations. For example, `Show` would be a mapping of types to functions which return strings. [This article](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/typeclass.html) explains this in more detail and also gives some alternative ways to implement type classes.

In a language that doesn't support types at all, you will have to implement the types as some kind of unique value which you can pass to polymorphic functions — such as a string, symbol, or object reference. I prefer an object reference because it means I can implement my types as functions and gain the ability to implement parameterized types.

Here's an example of how you could implement `Read` for `Maybe` and `Int`:

```js
// MACROS
const TYPE = (constructor, ...args) => Object.freeze({ constructor, args });
const TYPECLASS = (name, defaultMethods = {}) => {
  const id = Symbol(name);
  const typeClass = ({ constructor, args }) => {
    return Object.assign({}, defaultMethods, constructor[id](...args));
  };
  typeClass._instance_ = (constructor, implementation) => {
    constructor[id] = implementation;
  };
  return Object.freeze(typeClass);
};

// TYPES
const Int   = () => TYPE(Int);
const Maybe = a => TYPE(Maybe, a);

// DATA CONSTRUCTORS
const Just    = x => r => f => f(x);
const Nothing =      r => f => r;

// TYPE CLASSES and INSTANCES
const Read = TYPECLASS('Read');

Read._instance_(Maybe, A => ({
  read: str =>
    str.slice(0, 5) === "Just "
      ? Just (Read(A).read(str.slice(5)))
      : str === "Nothing"
        ? Nothing
        : undefined
}));

Read._instance_(Int, () => ({
  read: str => {
    const num = parseInt(str);
    return isNaN(num) ? undefined : num;
  }
}));

// FUNCTIONS
const error = msg => { throw new Error(msg); };
const maybe = x => f => m => m(x)(f);
const isJust = maybe (false) (_ => true);
const fromJust = maybe (undefined) (x => x);
const read = A => str => {
  const x = Read(A).read(str);
  return x === undefined ? error ("read: no parse") : x;
};
const readMaybe = A => str => {
  try       { return Just (read (A) (str)); }
  catch (e) { return Nothing; }
};

// TESTS
console.log([
  fromJust (read (Maybe(Int())) ("Just 123")), // 123
  read (Int()) ("123"),                        // 123  
  fromJust (readMaybe (Int()) ("abc"))         // undefined
]);
```

Comment: I am particularly interested in functions that are polymorphic in their return type, i.e. the context determines of what type the return value of a function finally is. I'll look at your answer in more detail later. Thanks!

Comment: Essentially my answer works by identifying all the type signatures which have a `=>` and changing it to a `->`. For an example, look at `readMaybe`. I didn't fully implement a type inference algorithm, so that type parameter has to be provided explicitly. I'd be interested to see how type inference could be implemented.

Comment: It's been a while, sorry, but `read (Maybe(Int())` looks like you pass the type itself to `read` rather than the function of the corresponding instance. Dispatching the right function depending on its type representation seems to be just an indirection, right? You probably did it for learning purposes. Anyway, using functions to represent types is a good idea.

Comment: @ftor Right, it was just a bit of indirection so that the syntax looked more Haskell-like. It also allows `readMaybe` to be implemented without adding it as a method of every type that implements `Read`.